# Looping through an array and comparing a variable to the array

Tags: javascript

As the subject suggests, I have an array that I would like to compare a variable containing a string to. I cannot seem to trigger the alert so I am assuming the comparison I am making in the `if` statement is being made incorrectly.

If anyone could correct me it would be greatly appreciated.

The first 4 variables here are to show you where the string came from.

```
var urlStr = window.location.href; ///index.html?_Spain_Germany_Russia
var urlStrDecode = decodeURI(urlStr);
var urlStrSplit = urlStrDecode.split('_');
var country = urlStrSplit[1];
function runFunction(){
    var countryList = ["Spain", "the United States", "France"];
    var countryListLength = countryList.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < countryListLength; i++) {
        if (country === countryList) {
            console.log('The country was matched');
        }
    }
}
runFunction();
```

Thank you.

Neil.

Comment: You are comparing country with the whole array. You should only pick one element : `if (country === countryList[i])`

Comment: you shoud compare with countryList[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify index to retrieve value from array.  `countryList[i]` will give you country

```
if (country === countryList[i]) {
            console.log('The country was matched');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate - you need to check the country against each item of the array, but this is a slightly different and more modern take on the loop that does not need the length of the array or an indexed array item.

```
var urlStr = window.location.href; ///index.html?_Spain_Germany_Russia
var urlStrDecode = decodeURI(urlStr);
var urlStrSplit = urlStrDecode.split('_');
var countryName = urlStrSplit[1];
function runFunction(){
    var countryList = ["Spain", "the United States", "France"];

    countryList.forEach(function(country){
       if(country === countryName) {
          console.log('The country was matched');
        }
    }}
}
runFunction();
```

or the good old indexOf...

```
var urlStr = window.location.href; ///index.html?_Spain_Germany_Russia
var urlStrDecode = decodeURI(urlStr);
var urlStrSplit = urlStrDecode.split('_');
var countryName = urlStrSplit[1];
function runFunction(){
    var countryList = ["Spain", "the United States", "France"];

    if(countryList.indexOf(countryName) !== -1) {
        console.log('The country was matched');
     }
    }
    runFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the country to the current element in the for loop.

```
var urlStr = 'index.html?_Spain_Germany_Russia'
var urlStrDecode = decodeURI(urlStr);
var urlStrSplit = urlStrDecode.split('_');
var country = urlStrSplit[1];
function runFunction(){
    var countryList = ["Spain", "the United States", "France"];
    var countryListLength = countryList.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < countryListLength; i++) {
        if (country === countryList[i]) {
            console.log('The country was matched');
        }
    }
}
runFunction();
```

Instead you can use builtin array method Array.includes(). The includes() 
method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning 
true or false as appropriate

```
countryList.includes(country) // true
```